# Не понимаю с чего начать и где взять достойные учебники

Tags: python, django, backend

Всем привет! Мне 14 лет, но уже серьезно решил заниматься программированием. Выучил основы Python, прочитал 2 учебника, могу уже маленькие программки-сценарии писать. Заинтересовала веб-разработка. Немного выучил HTML и надоело. Просто он мне чем то не нравится. Узнал что многие пишут сайты на Python-Django, так вот в чем вопрос, где взять хороший учебник по django 3, так как инет появляется редко, сайты не подойдут. Скачивать пытался, но ничего не выходило. И еще один вопрос: что еще учить для разработки? Именно бэкенда. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Советую прочитать книгу Н. Вирта "Алгоритмы и структуры данных". Вы слишком напираете на технологии, но к тому времени, когда вы придете в "большое" программирование они все изменятся.

Comment: http://kharchuk.ru/JavaScript.pdf это идеалная книга для javaScript но в этом книге нет EcmaScript 6

Comment: Читал это https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/ru/ Написано на русском и хорошо, главное не смущаться названию :D

Comment: @ՅուրիՍահակյան Не попал ответом ни в питон, ни в бэкенд 

Comment: Раз решили заниматься бэкендом, то без понимания теории баз данных не обойтись. Советую культовую книгу: Введение в системы баз данных К. Дж. Дейт